# How to findi duplicate entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am trying this code:

```
SELECT Email FROM 
(SELECT Email, COUNT(Email) AS cnt
FROM Person
GROUP BY Email
HAVING cnt(*) >1 )
```

for this question:
[image]
Not sure what I am getting wrong?

Here's the error I receive:

```
 Runtime Error Message: Line 6: SyntaxError: near '*) >1 )'
Last executed input: {"headers": {"Person": ["Id", "Email"]}, "rows": {"Person": []}}
```

Comment: As far as I can recall, 'cnt' isn't a valid function.  Try 'count'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select email
from person
group by email
having count(*)>1
```

You don't need the nested queries for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Email
FROM Person
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b914/1)

Comment: Thanks for introducing SQL Fiddle. But when I try your code it fails the tests `SELECT Email, COUNT(Email) AS cnt
FROM Person
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(*) >1`

Comment: update your question with the query you have written, I cant see anything wrong with this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select p.email from person p
 join (
 SELECT Email, COUNT(Email) AS cnt
 FROM Person
 GROUP BY Email
 HAVING count(email) > 1)  s
 on s.email = p.email
```

You can't use the alias of a column in the `having` or `where` clause.

Comment: how the exists operator will evaluate to true for each row returned by the outer query :) , even if you do make a correlated query by adding a where clause in exists operator query, it will be an overkill of a fairly simple problem.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I ran your code here but doesn't give me the answer I am looking for; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56c6a/1

Comment: @vkp: here's the error I get from running your code: `{"headers": {"Person": ["Id", "Email"]}, "rows": {"Person": []}}`

Comment: got it @M.Ali..i modified it as the OP only needs the email column.

Comment: modified the query @MonaJalal

Comment: this is making a simple query look complex though.